# Jade button and jQuery click event

Tags: jquery, pug

I don't get why it's not working...

I have this index.jade file:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")
           script
       $("#rollButton").click(function() {
          alert("sas");
       });
  body
     input#rollButton(type="button", value="Roll")
```

It should pop up the alert! What am I missing?

Generated HTML seems OK:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
$("#rollButton").click(function() {
  alert("sas");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="rollButton" type="button" value="Roll">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just view the generated page source? The answer should be obvious there

Comment: your indent of script is wrong

Comment: btw if you don't want to go crazy i would just put html in jade, require your scripts there and write your javascript code in another file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [jade] yet, but shouldn't there be jQuery "onReady" function, like this one:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")
    script
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#rollButton").click(function() {
          alert("sas");
         });
       });
  body
     input#rollButton(type="button", value="Roll")
```

EDIT: And I'm not sure about the indentation. It should be fixed too, as I see in other comments.

Comment: god, can't believe I missed the $(document).ready haha, been struggling for like half hour. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this !!! 5

```
html
 head
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")
       script
   $("#rollButton").click(function() {
      alert("sas");
   });
body
 input#rollButton(type="button", value="Roll")
```